# Last day of existence in table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to find a day the most recent day someone was in the table before they dropped out of it during a subsetted time range?

I have something like:

```
  SELECT 
     id
    , MAX(day) AS day
  FROM table
  WHERE 
       day >= '2018-01-01' AND day <= '2019-08-17'
       AND day != '2019-08-18'
  GROUP BY 1
```

I'm trying to just get everyone who was within the date range '2018-01-01' and '2019-08-17', but then wasn't in the table on '2019-08-18'

But, this still leads me to capture people who did have a day on '2019-08-18' in the original table, the new table just leaves that day out instead of finding people who truly didn't have a record in that day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT id, MAX(day) AS day
FROM table
WHERE day >= '2018-01-01' 
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(day) <= '2019-08-17';
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN day BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-08-17' THEN day END) AS day
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN day BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-08-17' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
  AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN day = '2019-08-18' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```